# F# cube root unit of measure

Tags: f#

Does F# have a built in cube root function? I know I can use exponentiation to compute cuberoots but it won't type check in my case since I want to take the cuberoot of a quantity of type float and get a float.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a built-in function to calculate the cube root with units of measure (I assume it would be in the [primitive operators module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353754.aspx) where `sqrt` and others are), so I think the only option is to use exponentiation.

However, you can use exponentiation without units and wrap the unit-unsafe operation in a function that adds units, so you get function with correct units:

```
let cuberoot (f:float<'m^3>) : float<'m> = 
  System.Math.Pow(float f, 1.0/3.0) |> LanguagePrimitives.FloatWithMeasure
```

Note that F# does not support [fractional units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333135/fractional-power-of-units-of-measures-in-f) so you can write `cuberoot (10.0<m^3>)` or `cuberoot (10.0<m^9>)`, but if you write `cuberoot (10.0<m>)` then it will not type-check, because the result would be meters to `1/3` (and that's a fractional unit).

This sample is only implementing `cuberoot` for `float`. If you wanted to write overloaded function that works with other numeric types (I guess you might need `float32`) then it gets a bit uglier (so I would not recommend that unless necessary), but you can use a trick with intermediate type with multiple overloads like, for example, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121556/overloading-measure-operator/14122388#14122388).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's a bit disappointing but I can live with this solution.

Comment: IMO using LanguagePrimitives.FloatWithMeasure instead of unbox will be more descriptive (and -1 boxing operation)

Comment: @desco Good point, thanks! Using `FloatWithMeasure` is definitely a better choice. I updated the answer.